# Extract IP addresses from system report

Tags: python, regex

I traverse the address entries, using a Python regex to extract addresses to add to my list.  Here is a sample input string and desired output.  How do I do this?

```
var = """

sw1:FID256:root> ipaddrshow 

CHASSIS
Ethernet IP Address: 10.17.11.10
Ethernet Subnetmask: 255.255.210.0

CP0
Ethernet IP Address: 10.17.11.11
Ethernet Subnetmask: 255.255.210.0
Host Name: cp0
Gateway IP Address: 10.17.48.1

CP1
Ethernet IP Address: 10.17.11.12
Ethernet Subnetmask: 255.255.210.0
Host Name: cp1
Gateway IP Address: 10.17.18.1

sw1:FID256:root>
"""
```

**Output:**

```
List Index 0 “chassis,ip 10.17.11.10 chassis,mask 255.255.210.0”

List Index 1 “cp0,ip 10.17.11.11 cp0,mask 255.255.210.0 cp0,gw 10.17.18.1”

List Index 2 “cp1,ip 10.17.11.12 cp1,mask 255.255.240.0 cp1,gw 10.17.18.1”
```

Comment: Cleaned up grammar, clarified problem statement, removed unneeded tags.

Comment: You have two useful answers.  Please accept your favourite, and post your follow-up question as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/eC0nV7/1) that extracts all the data:

```
(?m)^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\r?\n|\r)Ethernet IP Address: ([\d.]+)(?:\r?\n|\r)Ethernet Subnetmask: ([\d.]+)(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)Host Name: ([a-z\d]+)(?:\r?\n|\r)Gateway IP Address: ([\d.]+))?
```

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode to let `^` match a line start
- `^` - lime start
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - Group 1, one or more alphanumerics
- `(?:\r?\n|\r)` - a linebreak
- `Ethernet IP Address:` - literal string
- `([\d.]+)` - Group 2, 1+ digits and dots
- `(?:\r?\n|\r)Ethernet Subnetmask: ([\d.]+)` - similar pattern to above with Group 3 containing subnetmask
- `(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)Host Name: ([a-z\d]+)`  - similar pattern to above  with Group 4 containing host name
- `(?:\r?\n|\r)Gateway IP Address: ([\d.]+))?` - similar pattern to above  with Group 5 containing gateway.

Now, all you need is to use `re.finditer` and build the resulting string:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\r?\n|\r)Ethernet IP Address: ([\d.]+)(?:\r?\n|\r)Ethernet Subnetmask: ([\d.]+)(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)Host Name: ([a-z\d]+)(?:\r?\n|\r)Gateway IP Address: ([\d.]+))?', re.MULTILINE)
s = "sw1:FID256:root> ipaddrshow \n\nCHASSIS\nEthernet IP Address: 10.17.11.10\nEthernet Subnetmask: 255.255.210.0\n\nCP0\nEthernet IP Address: 10.17.11.11\nEthernet Subnetmask: 255.255.210.0\nHost Name: cp0\nGateway IP Address: 10.17.48.1\n\nCP1\nEthernet IP Address: 10.17.11.12\nEthernet Subnetmask: 255.255.210.0\nHost Name: cp1\nGateway IP Address: 10.17.18.1\n\nsw1:FID256:root>"
result = ["{0},ip {1} {0},mask {2} {3},gw {4}".format(z.group(1).lower(),z.group(2),z.group(3).lower(),z.group(4),z.group(5)) if z.group(4) else "{0},ip {1} {0},mask {2}".format(z.group(1).lower(),z.group(2),z.group(3)) for z in p.finditer(s)]
print(result)
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JebjLp).

Comment: thank you so much..now i got it..but i need more solution.Now i want to make a dictionary from the above list[output] and values to be returned as chassis,ip, chassis,mask, cp0,ip, cp0,mask, cp0,gw, cp1,ip, cp1,mask, cp1,gw @Wiktor Stribiżew.

Comment: That is already a different question. Please consider accepting the answer for the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar laying around and covers any attributes using a dictionary:

```
(?P<name>^[A-Z0-9]+)\n|(?P<attr>^[\w]+[^:]+):\s(?P<val>[\d\w\.]+)\n
```

In python is not possible to recover intermediate captures from groups that match more than once per regex match (as far as I know), but some of mine horrible python should do the work.

I also made a random dictionary because to me is not clear what you are asking.

```
import re

var = """

sw1:FID256:root> ipaddrshow 

CHASSIS
Ethernet IP Address: 10.17.11.10
Ethernet Subnetmask: 255.255.210.0

CP0
Ethernet IP Address: 10.17.11.11
Ethernet Subnetmask: 255.255.210.0
Host Name: cp0
Gateway IP Address: 10.17.48.1

CP1
Ethernet IP Address: 10.17.11.12
Ethernet Subnetmask: 255.255.210.0
Host Name: cp1
Gateway IP Address: 10.17.18.1

sw1:FID256:root>
"""

rgx = re.compile(r'(?P<name>^[A-Z0-9]+)\n|(?P<attr>^[\w]+[^:]+):\s(?P<val>[\d\w\.]+)\n', re.MULTILINE)

dict = {
    "Ethernet IP Address": "ip",
    "Ethernet Subnetmask": "mask",
    "Gateway IP Address": "gw",
    "Host Name": ""
}

def translate(attr):
    return dict[attr]

def build_list(r):
    entry = ""
    name = ""

    for l in rgx.finditer(var):

        if(l.group("name")):
            if(entry):
                r.append(entry[:-1])
                entry = ""

            name = l.group("name").lower()

        elif(l.group("attr")):
            varname = translate(l.group("attr"))
            value = l.group("val")

            if(varname != ""):
                entry += "{0},{1} {2} ".format(name, varname, value)

    # add last entry
    r.append(entry[:-1])
    entry = ""

def build_dict(d):
    entry = ""
    name = ""

    for l in rgx.finditer(var):

        if(l.group("name")):
            name = l.group("name").lower()
            d[name] = {}
        elif(l.group("attr")):
            varname = translate(l.group("attr"))
            value = l.group("val")

            if(varname != ""):
                d[name][varname] = value

r = []

build_list(r)

print r

d = {}

build_dict(d)

print d
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/DBkR2E)